# Core Data Migration From Branch To Trunk

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I come across a core data migration situation and wonder if anyone have any suggestions.

Short version - we have a **v1.5** core data model in **trunk** (**based off v1.0**), and a **v2.0** core data model in **branch** (which is also **based off v1.0**).  How should we merge the v2.0 data model with changes from v1.5?

Long version:
Our original app has v1.0 of our core data model.  After we have released the app, we started to develop v2.0 of the data model (based off v1.0) in a branch.  During v2.0 development, our maintenance team found a bug on v1.0 and created a v1.5 core data model (based off v1.0) in the trunk.  Now we have finished v2.0 development, we need to merge the branch changes back to trunk and the v2.0 data model will need to be merged with v1.5.  Does anyone have suggestion how I should go about this? Can I reset the base version of v2.0 data model and make it based off v1.5?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should never have several versions with the same version number, because version numbers were invented to uniquely identify versions. If you use the same version number for several different versions, then how will the users of your work know by seeing version 2.0 which 2.0 version is in their hand? You should create a sub-version, like version 2.0.1 and this way everybody will know that version 2.0 contained bugs which were fixed in version 2.0.1.

Comment: Lajos, I don't have several versions with the same version number.  What happened is that I have v1.5 data model contains bug fixes that are based on v1.0, and I also have a v2.0 data model contains new features that are based off v1.0 (so v2.0 doesn't have the bug fixes).  v1.5 is in trunk, and v2.0 is in branch.  The reason this happened is that v1.5 is a patch to the current version app and it was released while v2.0 is in development.